# Textbox Save Data into Object Variable WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

So basically my problem is that I have 2 forms one is for filling playernames (4players) if the user doesn't fills one or all the textboxes a random name will generate using streamreader, so that part is everything fine, but my issue is I save everything into my variable, but when trying to use the same variable in the other form it won't let me it's empty

```
    public class Player  //my classs and my player variable
        {
            
         
            string namee; 
            public string Namee { get => name; set => name = value; }
        }
```

Form 1 Code

```
 private void bPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Player p1 = new Player();
           if (tbPlayer1.Text.Equals("")) //And that's the same code for all the players 
            {
                rnName = rname.Next(1, 101);
                rnLastName = rlastname.Next(1, 101);
                p1.Namee += nameList[rnName] + lastnameList[rnLastName];
            }
            else
            {
                p1.Namee = tbPlayer1.Text;
                
            }
from2.Show();
    }
```

Now in my form 2 at the start

```
public Gameplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
        tbGameplayMessage.Text += " Some text " + p1.Namee;
    }
```

And it only show Some text in my textbox of the secondform

Thanks for all the help!! :D

Comment: Your Player p1 isn't being passed properly to Form 2. Also, how is p1 in Form 2 being instantiated? I'd guess in Form 2 you have above Gameplay():

`Player p1 = new Player();`

Comment: Easiest fix would be to create a [C# Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) in Form 2, then in Form 1 after `form2.Show()` you could call:

`form2.p1 = p1;`

Comment: Besides `Property` Mercifies mentioned, you can also pass "p1.Namee" to Form2 through a custom Form2 constructor.

Comment: How can I do that @KyleWang? and which would be better?

Comment: Just put form2.p1 = p1? @Mercifies

Answer (score 0):

**Solution A (Constructor):**

Define a string to store the value passed from `p1.namee` and a constructor with a `string parameter` for `Gameplay class`.

```
public partial class Gameplay : Form
{
    public Gameplay(string na)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        namee = na;
    }

    string namee;

    // show the text
    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labeltoShow.Text = namee;
    }
}
```

Then modify `bPlay_Click` as followed.

```
private void bPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Player p1 = new Player();
    p1.Namee = tbPlayer1.Text; // for test

    Gameplay form2 = new Gameplay(p1.Namee);
    form2.Show();
}
```

---

**Solution B (Property)**

Define a property `Namee` in class `Gameplay`.

```
public partial class Gameplay : Form
{
    public Gameplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Namee { get; set; }

    // show the text
    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labeltoShow.Text = Namee;
    }
}
```

Then set this property in `bPlay_Click` before `Show()` called.

```
private void bPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Player p1 = new Player();
    p1.Namee = tbPlayer1.Text;

    Gameplay form2 = new Gameplay();
    form2.Namee = p1.Namee;
    form2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Is this answer helpful to you? If yes, please [mark it as answer or vote up it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).